# I can't update blocks in Notion API

Tags: python, python-requests, notion-api

How can I update my block with Notion? I've tried to follow the instructions on how to update the API but failed. Even when using `requests.patch`, the response text doesn't change.

Here's the code:

```py
import json, requests
import dotenv, os

def main():
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv.find_dotenv())
    TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")
    BLOCK_ID = os.environ.get("BLOCK_ID")
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN,
        "Notion-Version": "2021-08-16"
    }

    new_body = {
        "paragraph": {
            "text": [{
                "text": {
                    "content": "bye bye"
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    readurl = f"https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/{BLOCK_ID}"

    # res = requests.request("PATCH", readurl, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(new_body))
    res = requests.patch(readurl, headers=headers, data=new_body)
    print(res.status_code)
    print(json.dumps(json.loads(res.text), indent=2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The status code and text are:

```
200
{
  # other properties... then,
  "paragraph": {
    "text": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": {
          "content": "hello there!",
          "link": null
        },
        "annotations": {
          "bold": true,
          "italic": false,
          "strikethrough": false,
          "underline": false,
          "code": false,
          "color": "default"
        },
        "plain_text": "hello there!",
        "href": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cause u miss Content_Type on header

try change to

```
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + TOKEN,
        "Notion-Version": "2021-08-16"
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

the data value will ignore when no content-Type on header, so the 200 respond will show as no data value provide for change.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change `data=new_body` to `json=new_body`

Comment: Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow! Considering that your answer is an addition to an earlier (already accepted) answer, I suggest that you add your answer as a comment to the earlier answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34836911)